# How to approximate higher-degree multivariate polynomial in space of lower-degree multivariate polynomials with some constraints?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, approximation-theory, nonlinear-optimization

For a polynomial $P_{1}(x)$, $x\in {\mathbb R}^n$ with a higher-degree, how to find a lower-degree polynomial $P_{2}(x)$ with determined structure or bounded degree to approximate it with the constraint: $$\{x|P_{2}(x) \le 0\} \subseteq \{x|P_{1}(x) \le 0\}$$ I hope the algorithm can manipulate coefficients directly and be free from computing the value of $P_{i}(x)$. However, a high efficient algorithm which needs to compute $P_{i}(x)$ is acceptable as well.